# How to compute the support of an element $f \in A$? A a finite type $k$-algebra.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is there a good algorithm for computing this? I understand that a reasonable first step would be to compute the annihilator of $f$, but I don't know how to do that (except in the simplest examples).

Let me give an example of an element whose annihilator I don't know how to algebraically.

$g = y - 1 \in k[x,y] / (xy(x - 1, y))$.

Here is what I am thinking about this: Z(y - 1) intersects the variety $Z(xy(x - 1,y))$ only at the point $(x,y) = (0,1)$ (based on my computation anyway). Therefore, the set $D(g)$ is dense in $X = spec k[x,y] / (xy(x - 1, y))$, so the support of $g$ is a closed subset containing a dense subset, so is all of $X$. This means that $g$ is not a zero divisor, since it does not vanish at any of the associated points, hence its annihilator is $(xy(x-1,y))$.

Is that reasoning correct? Is there an easier method to compute the annihilator of $g$?

(Random question: is there an "interesting" closed subscheme structure to put on $supp g$, that is not just reduced induced?)

Comment: $k[x,y]/(xy(y-1),y)=k[x,y]/(y)$ and thus the annihilator of $y-1=-1$ is zero in this ring or just $yk[x,y]$ in the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$.

Comment: @Mohan That is a good point.